# Inner product on function whose domain is finite set

Tags: inner-products

I'm curious how can I define inner product between two functions whose domains are finite sets.
I know function's inner product is defined as $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f \cdot g \space dx\space\space $ But domains of $f$ and $g$ are to be $[a, b]$ in this case, which are (continuous) infinite sets.

To get more examples, what is $\langle f, g \rangle\space$ **if** $\space f(x)=x\space$ **and** $\space g(x)=x+3 \space \space$ **for**  $x\in\{1, 2, 3\}$ (-> finite domain)

I think it would be $(1, 2, 3)\cdot(4,5,6)=32\space$ because the range of $f\space $ is $\{1, 2, 3\}\space$ and it is $\{4,5,6\}$ for $g$. But I can't be sure.
Does anybody know this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try checking if the dot product of the range in order satisfies the axioms of an inner product?

Comment: Inner product is defined on Vector Spaces. So unless you specify the Vector Space , Inner Product has no meaning.

Comment: In fact, the set of all real-valued functions defined on $\{1,2,3\}$ is nothing else than $\mathbb R^3$ ...  You've just defined the standard dot product on it.